# How to call method of @UiField field in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder

here are my classes

```
public class PersonView extends Composite{

    private Person person;

    @UiField
    FirstnameView firstnameView;
    @UiField
    LastnameView lastnameView;

    public PersonView(Person person) {
        setData(person);
    }

    public void setData(Person person) {
        firstnameView.setData(person.getFirstname());
        lastnameView.setData(person.getLastname());
    }
}
public class FirstnameView extends Composite{

        private Firstname firstname;

        @UiField
        TextBox firstnameTextBox;

        public FirstnameView() {
        }

        public void setData(Firstname firstname) {
            firstnameTextBox.setValue(firstname.getFirstname());
        }
    }
public class LastnameView extends Composite{

        private Lastname lastname;

        @UiField
        TextBox lastnameTextBox;

        public LastnameView() {
        }

        public void setData(Lastname lastname) {
            lastnameTextBox.setValue(lastname.getLastname());
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I call method `setData(person)`, I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null in the line `firstnameView.setData(person.getFirstname())`
```

I think that `@UiField FirstnameView firstnameView` (and the `lastnameView` too) doesn't create an object. I really don't understand how gwt works in this case. Help me please resolve it and set data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@UiField`s are only "injected" when you call `initAndBindUi` on a `UiBinder` instance, passing an instance with the `@UiField`s as argument.

In other words, your `PersonView` constructor should begin with initializing a `UiBinder` instance and calling `binder.initAndBindUi(this)` before you can call `setData()`.